# Converting a numbers

Tags: t-sql

I have a calculation and had it working (section2) and then we needed to change the calculation too:((bkesty * 12) - bkdptime)/12 and not sure how to fit it in to change the results 5.6666 to 5y8m.

Section 1 New Calculation

bkesty value = 14.75
bkdptime = 109

```sql
select ((bkesty * 12) - bkdptime)/12  as "ESTIMATED_LIFE"
from AMASST where ASTNO = 'DR-080426'
```

Result is 5.6666

Then I need the result to display 5y8m

It works with the old calculation down below, I am not sure how to change the formula to get the results with the above calculation in section1

Section 2 Old calculation

```sql
select left(bkesty,charindex('.', bkesty)-1) + 'y' + convert(varchar,floor((CONVERT(float,convert(float,RIGHT(bkesty,3))*12)))) + 'm' as "ESTIMATED_LIFE"
```

Any help would be great

Comment: It looks like Ye Olde Calculation would take `5.6666 years` through `5 years and 7.992 months` to `5Y7M`. How do you get `8 months`? Is the period ever negative? What are the data types of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. You may want to use [`Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to tweak the number of months.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @AMASST as Table ( ASTNO VarChar(10), bkesty Float, bkdptime Float );
insert into @AMASST ( ASTNO, bkesty, bkdptime ) values
  ( 'DR-080426', 5.6666, 0.0000 );

-- The following assumes that the estimated life is never negative.
select ASTNO, bkesty, bkdptime, EstLife,
  -- Just take the integer part for the years.
  Floor( EstLife ) as IntegerYears,
  -- Subtract the integer part from the floating value to get the fractional part.
  -- Multiply by 12 to get the number of months, take the integer part.
  ( EstLife - Floor( EstLife ) ) * 12 as FloatingMonths,
  -- Put it all together with casts to strings.
  Cast( Floor( EstLife ) as VarChar(4) ) + 'y' +
    Cast( Floor( ( EstLife - Floor( EstLife ) ) * 12 ) as VarChar(2) ) + 'm' as "ESTIMATED_LIFE"
  from @AMASST cross apply
    -- Perform the New Calculation and make it available as   EstLife .
    ( select ( ( bkesty * 12 ) - bkdptime ) / 12 as EstLife ) Placeholder
  where ASTNO = 'DR-080426';
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't divide by 12 at the end.  You already have an integer number of months.  Dividing by 12 gives you the number of years, but there will be round off error.

Once you have the total number of months, divide by 12 to get the number of years, 
and the remainder will be the months.

```
create function dbo.MonthsToStr ( @Months int ) 
returns varchar(20) as
begin
  declare @Result varchar(20)
  -- Do we need to deal with negative values?

  if @Months < 0 
    set @Result =  '-' + dbo.MonthsToStr(-@Months)
  else
    -- Divide by 12 to get the number of years
    -- The remainder is the number of months
    set @Result =  CAST(@Months/12 as varchar(10) ) + 'y'
                 + CAST(@months%12 as varchar(2) ) + 'm'

  return @Result
end
go

select dbo.MonthsToStr(68)
```